# MeteorJS Get image width

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, meteor

I'm using "react-dropzone" to provide the users a way to upload their images. When a user submits I save the images in the amazon S3 cloud. I need to measure the image width but I already tried the imagemagick package and some other npm modules and I always have some problem like "Cannot find module "fs"" or "Cannot find module '../lib/detector'(…)". Any suggestions?

```
    S3.upload({
            files:this.files,
            path:"tours/"+this.tourId
        },function(e,result){
         // Get Image width here
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `file` should have a `.preview` property on it (unless you set `disablePreview` prop). The `file.preview` is the a blob URL that you can load into an `Image()` to capture the width and height in its `onload` event:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file.preview);
image.onload = function () {
  var width = image.width;
  var height = image.height;
  // TODO: Do something with the dimensions
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The fs module is only available on the server, as is imagemagick. So you would need to pass the images to your meteor server to use them.

Alternatively AWS S3 has lambda functions (which can be in javascript) and can be triggered when you upload a file, so you could do the detection there. You could save the image information to a separate text file on AWS, and then retrieve that using a HTTP GET request. The only issue with this is that the lambda function executes asynchronously, so you would need to wait some time before requesting the file.

The AWS API Gateway allows you to invoke lambda functions using a HTTP request, so as soon as the file upload is complete, your next action would be to do a HTTP GET of the lambda function. This will return you the information you need.